# Symfony2 WebProfiler (500): Key "default" does not exist as the array is empty in @Doctrine/Collector/db.html.twig at line 209

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-sonata

Symfony2 WebProfiler (500): Key "default" does not exist as the array is empty in @Doctrine/Collector/db.html.twig at line 209

I have installed Sonata e-commerce 2.3 branch (fresh installation) on several machines (php 5.4, php 5.5), everything works fine, but and on each one i have the same error in profiler doctrine DB tab:

```
Symfony2 WebProfiler (500): Key "default" does not exist as the array is empty in @Doctrine/Collector/db.html.twig at line 209
```

Profiler is working fine only after first request (when cache is empty), after the next request there is the error. 
I was searching the web for the solution, but without success..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can override @Doctrine/Collector/db.html.twig template by your own. Just add condition `if collector.mappingErrors[manager] is defined` in your new template on line 209.