# Symfony 2: webprofile TWIG_ERROR_RUNTIME

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig, runtime-error

I am building up a reproduction testlab using several virtual machines to be able to recreate production issues (provisioning portal webserver / postgresql DB / radius server / etc...). The provisioning portal is used to create user profiles in our production setup for the service we provide to our end customers and is based on the symfony2 framework.

I am reverse engineering things due to no support from the integrator of the entire solution (the code development was outsourced by them and I have no personal experience with the symfony framework - PHP aware but no a strong knowledge here neither that I would feel comfortable to do major changes in the programming). 
Things done:

1. installed VM -> runs ubuntu 16.04 - installed apache / php /postgresql /etc on it
2. replication DB from production unto this testbed setup
3. Replicate PHP settings from production (downgraded to php 5.6 and installed missing php packages like bcmath)
4. copied the full www of the production webserver unto the test setup and modified it from prod to dev so I can run the webprofiler on the testbed

I have the webprofiler running now on the testbed. A problem I am encountering is when trying to render the DB queries details via the webprofile menubar:

[image: symfony webprofile]

A TWIG_RUNTIME_ERROR is shown as next screen:
[image: runtime error]

> Twig_Error_Runtime: Key "default" does not exist as the array is
>   empty in "DoctrineBundle:Collector:db.html.twig" at line 209
>       at n/a in /var/www/provisioningportal/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php
>   line 393

The same issue was already identified on this thread:
[Symfony2 WebProfiler (500): Key "default" does not exist as the array is empty in @Doctrine/Collector/db.html.twig at line 209](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276661/symfony2-webprofiler-500-key-default-does-not-exist-as-the-array-is-empty-i)
but I am not understanding the reason why another rendering template could help here. Routing wise it seems OK to me (checked app/log/ap__dev.log). For me, there is some data missing to be rendered in this template.

Root cause could be the way I tried to set up things as this is most likely not a best common practice (any pointer to how are welcome but documentation starts almost always from the other way where you start a project and now how you shoudl be importing a project like I do here). 
I am calling out for help on how to resolve the runtime error issue... Any ideas here?

INFO:

```
awk5303@ubuntu:/var/www/provisioningportal# composer show

behat/behat                              v2.5.3             
behat/common-contexts                    v1.2.0             
behat/gherkin                            v2.3.5             
behat/mink                               v1.6.0             
behat/mink-browserkit-driver             v1.2.0             
behat/mink-extension                     v1.3.3             
behat/mink-goutte-driver                 v1.1.0             
behat/mink-selenium2-driver              v1.2.0             
behat/transliterator                     v1.0.1             
dflydev/markdown                         v1.0.3             
doctrine/annotations                     v1.2.1             
doctrine/cache                           v1.3.1             
doctrine/collections                     v1.2               
doctrine/common                          v2.4.2             
doctrine/data-fixtures                   dev-master ac36ccc 
doctrine/dbal                            v2.5.0             
doctrine/doctrine-bundle                 v1.3.0             
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle           v1.0.1             
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle        v2.2.0             
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle      dev-master 81575a4 
doctrine/inflector                       v1.0               
doctrine/instantiator                    1.0.4              
doctrine/lexer                           v1.0               
doctrine/migrations                      dev-master f4fe9d9 
doctrine/orm                             v2.4.6             
egeloen/ckeditor-bundle                  2.5.2              
egeloen/json-builder                     1.0.3              
fabpot/goutte                            v1.0.7             
friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle          dev-master 2363b47 
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle             1.4.2              
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle             v1.3.5             
fzaninotto/faker                         v1.4.0             
gedmo/doctrine-extensions                dev-master b1c3643 
guzzle/guzzle                            v3.9.2             
imagine/imagine                          0.6.2              
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler     v2.1.0             
instaclick/php-webdriver                 1.4.1              
jdorn/sql-formatter                      v1.2.17            
jms/aop-bundle                           1.0.1              
jms/cg                                   1.0.0              
jms/di-extra-bundle                      1.5.0              
jms/metadata                             1.5.1              
jms/parser-lib                           1.0.0              
jms/security-extra-bundle                1.5.1              
jms/serializer                           0.16.0             
jms/serializer-bundle                    dev-master 05965e0 
kitpages/semaphore-bundle                v1.4.0             
knplabs/gaufrette                        v0.1.4             
knplabs/knp-components                   1.3.1              
knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle              1.2.0              
knplabs/knp-menu                         v2.0.1             
knplabs/knp-menu-bundle                  v2.0.0             
knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle             2.4.1              
kriswallsmith/assetic                    v1.2.1             
kriswallsmith/buzz                       v0.13              
lunetics/locale-bundle                   dev-master d5bb6fb 
michelf/php-markdown                     1.4.1              
monolog/monolog                          1.11.0             
mopa/bootstrap-bundle                    v3.0.0-beta3       
mopa/composer-bridge                     v1.3.0             
nelmio/api-doc-bundle                    2.7.0              
phpcollection/phpcollection              0.4.0              
phpoption/phpoption                      1.4.0              
phpunit/php-code-coverage                2.0.13             
phpunit/php-file-iterator                1.3.4              
phpunit/php-text-template                1.2.0              
phpunit/php-timer                        1.0.5              
phpunit/php-token-stream                 1.3.0              
phpunit/phpunit                          4.4.0              
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects             2.3.0              
psr/log                                  1.0.0              
sebastian/comparator                     1.1.0              
sebastian/diff                           1.2.0              
sebastian/environment                    1.2.1              
sebastian/exporter                       1.0.2              
sebastian/global-state                   1.0.0              
sebastian/version                        1.0.3              
sensio/distribution-bundle               v2.3.6             
sensio/framework-extra-bundle            v2.3.4             
sensio/generator-bundle                  v2.5.0             
simplethings/entity-audit-bundle         dev-master 4f9942a 
sonata-project/admin-bundle              2.3.0              
sonata-project/block-bundle              2.2.13             
sonata-project/cache                     1.0.4              
sonata-project/cache-bundle              2.2.0              
sonata-project/classification-bundle     2.2.2              
sonata-project/comment-bundle            dev-master 701040a 
sonata-project/core-bundle               2.3.0              
sonata-project/datagrid-bundle           dev-master dba166c 
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions       1.0.2              
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 2.3.0              
sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle       2.1.9              
sonata-project/ecommerce                 dev-develop af77223
sonata-project/exporter                  1.3.4              
sonata-project/formatter-bundle          2.3.2              
sonata-project/google-authenticator      1.0.2              
sonata-project/intl-bundle               2.2.1              
sonata-project/media-bundle              2.3.0              
sonata-project/news-bundle               2.3.5              
sonata-project/notification-bundle       2.3.0              
sonata-project/page-bundle               2.3.8              
sonata-project/seo-bundle                1.1.8              
sonata-project/timeline-bundle           dev-master 2765d6d 
sonata-project/user-bundle               2.2.4              
stephpy/timeline                         v1.0.3             
stephpy/timeline-bundle                  2.1.0              
stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle          dev-master 2ff8473 
swiftmailer/swiftmailer                  v5.3.1             
symfony-cmf/routing                      1.3.0              
symfony-cmf/routing-bundle               1.3.3              
symfony/assetic-bundle                   v2.5.0             
symfony/icu                              v1.2.2             
symfony/intl                             2.7.x-dev fec7221  
symfony/monolog-bundle                   v2.6.1             
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle               v2.3.8             
symfony/symfony                          v2.6.1             
twbs/bootstrap                           v3.0.0             
twig/extensions                          v1.2.0             
twig/twig                                v1.16.2            
willdurand/faker-bundle                  1.2.1              
willdurand/jsonp-callback-validator      v1.1.0             
willdurand/negotiation                   1.3.4
```